# C++: Saving a large binary file (2GB to 4GB) to RAM in a char*?

Tags: c++, file-io, tcp, ftp

I am working on a **file transfer program** in C++ which converts a file to binary, saves the bytes in a char*, then sends that char* through a **TCP** connection to another computer. The other computer then recreates the file locally. The program does work, but I run into a big problem with large files! I cannot allocate enough array indexes to contain the bytes! For example, if I want to send a 600MB file, I need a char* with 600 MILLION indexes. This works. But once I go any higher, the program simply cannot allocate the memory and I get errors.

A friend of mine suggested that I split the file into chunks and do the transfer chunk by chunk, however this creates a plethora of other challenges and would require me to basically rewrite the entire program.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Well, even though memory is cheap, it is still *limited*.

Comment: "Sending by chunks" is the default method, that's how it's done in existing libraries (which you re-invent). Also, the problem in your case is not just amount of memory, but the size of the largest free piece (which can be much smaller, 600 Mb is lucky case).

Comment: How big is an "index"? (not sure to what you are referring here).  Also are you compiling/running on a 64 bit platform?  You will have more addressable memory there.  Of course you need to rewrite it to send the file over in chunks, if you want it to work irrespective of source or target memory size.  That's just a basic design choice.

Comment: Do you really need to read the whole file into memory at once? What do you mean by "converts ... to binary"? Why not read it as binary unformatted data to begin with?

Comment: What do you mean by indexes? Is this a x64 or x86 program?

Comment: A `char*` isn't big enough to hold more than a few bytes, certainly not 600 MILLION indexes. Go to the whiteboard and write 100 times: "an array is not a pointer".

Answer (score 6):

> A friend of mine suggested that I split the file into chunks and do the transfer chunk by chunk, however this creates a plethora of other challenges and would require me to basically rewrite the entire program.

This is why it's called computer science, and why once you have mastered these challenges, you can head to the city and earn the big bucks.

Comment: A better answer to this question simply doesn't exist. +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean with *converting to binary*, but you shouldn't have to allocate 600MB+ of memory, but work with buffering instead.

For example, to send a file from disk:

- open file
- read part of file in buffer
- send buffer over TCP connection (repeat until done)

You could also use memory mapping (or TransmitFile() in Windows).

In case your data needs to be converted:

- open file
- read part in buffer
- convert buffer
- send buffer (repeat)